# How to stop flickering from prompts when saving Excel rows to different file format?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA macro that saves Excel row data to .svg files. This code is working but I can't get the prompts to stop.

I want the code to work silently without throwing prompts after each conversion.

I am referring to the flickering not the actual prompts.

```
Sub SaveRowsAsSVGs()

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook, wbNew As Excel.Workbook
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet, wsTemp As Excel.Worksheet
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Images")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'will overwrite existing files without asking

r = 1
Do Until Len(Trim(wsSource.Cells(r, 1).Value)) = 0
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    For c = 2 To 7
        wsTemp.Cells((c - 1) * 2 - 1, 1).Value = wsSource.Cells(r, c).Value
    Next c

    wsTemp.Move
    Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsTemp = wbNew.Worksheets(1)
    Dim myPath As String
    myPath = "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Folder\Images\"
    wbNew.SaveAs myPath & wsSource.Cells(r, 1).Value & ".svg", xlCSV
    'wbNew.SaveAs "cell.Text" & r & ".svg", xlCSV 'new way
    wbNew.Close
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    r = r + 1
Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is working for me and I do not get any prompts. The "only"  issue is that the screen is flickering but that's because how the code is written.

Comment: I am referring to the flickering not the actual prompts. Anything I can try?

Comment: Worked after adding `Application.ScreenUpdating=False`